# Short display images by date newer to older in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using the following function to read a directory and show images as a gallery, it works really well, but I need to display images ordering by date from newer to older.

Knows anyone how to do it using this method?

```
function getPictures() {


        global $page, $per_page, $has_previous, $has_next;
        if ( $handle = opendir("saved/2013") ) {
            $lightbox = rand();

            $count = 0;
            $skip = $page * $per_page;


            if ( $skip != 0 )
                $has_previous = true;

            while ( $count < $skip && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
                if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' )
                    $count++;
            }
            $count = 0;
            while ( $count < $per_page && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
                if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' ) {
                    if ( ! is_dir('saved/2013') ) {
                        mkdir('saved/2013');
                    }


                    $strFileName = "saved/2013/".$file;
                    echo '<div id="imagen-t">';
                    echo '<p>' .date( "D d M Y g:i A", filemtime($strFileName)) . "</p>";
                    echo '<p><a href="saved/2013/'.$file.'" rel="lightbox['.$lightbox.']"><img src=saved/2013/'.$file.' alt="" width="220" /></a></p>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    $count++;
                }
            }


            while ( ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
                if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' ) {
                    $has_next = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the result:
http://www.espigoplatja.com/whale/galeria/

Salutations,
Gonzalo

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at USort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
It allows you to sort an array by values with user defined comparison function.

**An example**

```
<?php
function my_sort($a,$b)
{
if ($a==$b) return 0;
   return ($a<$b)?-1:1;
}

$a=array(4,2,8,6);
usort($a,"my_sort");

$arrlength=count($a);
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
   {
   echo $a[$x];
   echo "<br>";
   }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ali. Yes I have look usort, but the thing is that I don't know how to use it in the function I don't know much Php.

Comment: Did you try implementing the usort() for your example?

Comment: Another way to do it it could be making the index.php read form the last page right now Another way to do it I think it could be making the index.php start reading by the last page, now: http://www.espigoplatja.com/whale/galeria/?page=15

Answer (score 0):

By the way I try implementing the sample you provide and it displays the same date for all imagenes:

```
# SETTINGS
$per_page = 6;

$page = $_GET['page'];

$has_previous = false;
$has_next = false;




function getPictures() {


    global $page, $per_page, $has_previous, $has_next;
    if ( $handle = opendir("saved/2013") ) {
        $lightbox = rand();

        $count = 0;
        $skip = $page * $per_page;


        if ( $skip != 0 )
            $has_previous = true;



        while ( $count < $skip && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
            if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' )
                $count++;
        }

        function my_sort($a,$b)
        {
        if ($a==$b) return 0;
           return ($a<$b)?-1:1;
        }

        $count = 0;
        while ( $count < $per_page && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
            if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' ) {
                if ( ! is_dir('saved/2013') ) {
                    mkdir('saved/2013');
                }

                $a=array($file);
                usort($a,"my_sort");


                //$strFileName = "saved/2013/".$file;
                $strFileName = "saved/2013/".$a[$x];
                echo '<div id="imagen-t">';
                //echo '<p>' .date( "D d M Y g:i A", filemtime($strFileName)) . "</p>";
                echo '<p>' .date( "D d M Y g:i A", filemtime($strFileName)) . "</p>";
                echo '<p><a href="saved/2013/'.$file.'" rel="lightbox['.$lightbox.']"><img src=saved/2013/'.$file.' alt="" width="220" /></a></p>';
                echo '</div>';
                $count++;
            }
        }


        while ( ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
            if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' ) {
                $has_next = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```